# Getting the index of a selected item from a polymer core-list

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to scroll a simple core-list with a keyboard key.
This is the core-list:

**post-list.html**

```
<core-list data="{{posts}}" selectionEnabled="true" selection="{{selectedPost}}" on-core-select="{{selectedHandler}}" fit >
    <template repeat>
        <post-card post="{{model}}" index="{{index}}" ></post-card>     
    </template>
```

I need to get the index of the selected post-card, increment it and pass it to the *selectItem* and *scrollToItem* methods of the core-list.

The problem I'm facing is... how do i get the index?
I searched for an easy way to get the it both in core-list and in core-selection without success.

Unfortunately the core-list attribute "selection" from core-list is the data of the current selected record (so I can't get the index attribute from it).

Am I missing something? 
Is there any solution that doesn't involve handling the index directly in the post-card component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core-list item is core-selection which handling selection event. You could try to use core-select event which you could get the index of selected item. So it could be like this

```
selectedHandler: function(e, detail, sender) {
     var i=this.$.selection.indexOf(detail.item);
     this.scrollToItem(i+1);
   }
```

Comment: I was hoping for a cleaner solution (like _selectedIndex_ from _core-selector_) but thank you, this solution works too :)  in the end I just did this:   `var selectedIndex = this.posts.indexOf(this.post);`